# Understanding fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, methods

I am trying to understand how/why fetch_assoc works the way it does. 
I have the following piece of code:

```
$results = $connectToDb->fetch("SELECT * FROM customer");
$resultsArray = $results->fetch_assoc();
print_r($resultsArray);  //print_r 1

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);       //print_r 2
}
```

The query returns 3 rows from a table.
Why does the 1st print_r return only the 1st row of the queried data but the 2nd print_r returns all 3? How does putting fetch_assoc into a while loop tell it to do the action more than once? I read that fetch_assoc returns either an associative array or NULL but I'm struggling to understand how the while loop "tells" fetch_assoc to fetch the next row, if that makes sense?

Thank you.

Comment: Why does putting something in a loop make something happen more than once?

Comment: The meaning of a while statement is simple. It tells PHP to execute the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression evaluates to TRUE. The value of the expression is checked each time at the beginning of the loop, so even if this value changes during the execution of the nested statement(s), execution will not stop until the end of the iteration (each time PHP runs the statements in the loop is one iteration). Sometimes, if the while expression evaluates to FALSE from the very beginning, the nested statement(s) won't even be run once.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: The `$results` object returned from the database is an `iterator` ('cursor').  An `iterator` has a 'current row'. Every time you `fetch_assoc()` it returns the current row and **automatically advances to to the next row**. So, the while loop does not tell the database to return the next row, the `fetch_assoc()` does that, the while loop ends when it gets an empty row.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand, "it returns the current row and automatically advances to to the next row". How does it know to automatically advance to the next row if it is? Is there a counter or something within fetch_assoc? I'm not sure where to begin researching from here. Should I look up "iterator objects('cursors')"?

Comment: Correct! - The counter is in the `$result` object :) It is advance whenever you fetch a row from the result set. see: [The Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). for an example of the PHP iterator. All iterators have the same idea.

Answer (score 23):

Lets try to understand your code and how it works:

```
$results = $connectToDb->fetch("SELECT * FROM customer");
```

A variable `$results` has a collection of rows which are returned by a query. The size of the collection can be from 0 to n.

```
$resultsArray = $results->fetch_assoc();
```

This line fetch the first element from the collection. If the collection is empty it will return `NULL`.

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
}
```

It can be decoupled in the following steps:

1. Calculate `$row = $results->fetch_assoc()` and return **array with elements** or **NULL**.
2. Substitute `$row = $results->fetch_assoc()` in `while` with gotten value and get the following statements: `while(array(with elements))` or `while(NULL)`.
3. If it's `while(array(with elements))` it resolves the while condition in `True` and allow to perform an iteration.
4. If it's `while(NULL)` it resolves the while condition in `False` and exits the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think it useful:

```
function get_posts(){
$posts = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT  id, post_userid, name, lang, country, post_image, post_date, post_date_updated FROM posts ORDER BY `post_date` DESC ;")) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $posts[$row['id']] = $row ;   
    }
} else {
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
return $posts;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your case, if you want to print 3 rows each by each, you need to call this `$result->fetch_assoc()` as a three times.

for example, when you call the first time first row will be fetched and  removed from array list. then 2 rows remain now.

in Second call second row will fetched and removed from array list.then 1 row remain now.

so you can call 3 times because you have a 3 rows. it will give null value if you call fourth times.because array list is empty now.

now come to the `while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()` this also do the same job which we discussed above.